# Creating a state-space representation (.m format, Matlab) via Simcenter 3D (NASTRAN) using Component Mode Synthesis Reduction

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, modeling, nastran

I'm trying to create a state-space representation of my FE-model using a "Component Mode Synthesis Reduction" (general form of Craig-Brampton reduction). The picture underneath shows (approximately) the Nastran code I want to write. However I cannot add "RSMETHOD = 100", but instead the default text is "METHOD = 100" (I am writing text within the GUI of Simcenter 3D in the "Case control" of the solution). Because of that Nastran uses a normal modes reduction. How can I change the reduction method?

[image: screenshot from the Advanced Dynamic Analysis User's Guide p. 7.9]